# Play2: Is it possible to respond with 405 Method not allowed" instead of "404 Not Found" if a route exists, but not for the current method

Tags: playframework

When I put something like this into my routes file:

```
GET /foo com.example.controllers.FooController.foo
```

and then issue a request to this resource which is not `GET`, e.g. `POST /foo`, the default router responds with a 404 and an "Action not found". Is it somehow possible to have it detect that a resource exists for a different method and output a status code 405 (Method not allowed) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `onHandlerNotFound` method in `GlobalSettings` class:

> Called when no action was found to serve a request. The default behavior is to render the framework's default 404 page. This is achieved by returning null, so that the Scala engine handles onHandlerNotFound. By overriding this method one can provide an alternative 404 page.

More details [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaGlobal).

Comment: I came across this by myself in the meantime. Is there an efficient way of checking if a route exists for the same path but another method or do I have to iterate over all methods, send an `onRouteRequest` and check if any of the results is not `None`?

Comment: Why is this an error? For REST interfaces (this is what I am building with Play) it is totally common that there are multiple request methods defined for the same path... e.g. a todo list could have `GET /todos/:id` to view a todo, and `PUT /todos/:id` to add a todo with a specified id...

Comment: But this is, as I said, common in a REST interface, and the router of Play also supports it. In my todo example, I could define a route like `GET /todos/:id controllers.ToDoController.getTodo(id: Long)` and another one like `PUT /todos/:id controllers.ToDoController.putTodo(id: Long)`. The interface has to be correctly documented, though.

Comment: `Is there an efficient way of checking if a route exists for the same path but another method.` Sorry I have no visibility on this field. I would suggest asking new question.

Comment: I already found out that there is not because `Router.routes` is a `PartialFunction`, so I can only use `isDefinedAt` with an iteration over all request methods I use in my routes.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add The Class Global in your APP Folder and overwrite method onHandlerNotFound like this:

```
import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.mvc.Http.*;
import play.libs.F.*;

import static play.mvc.Results.*;

public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    public Promise<Result> onHandlerNotFound(RequestHeader request) {
        return Promise.<Result>pure(
                status(405, "Method Not Allowed")
        );
    }

}
```

Play framewrok doesn't have an Result for not allowed sou you must use Status https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/java/index.html

I think that you should write a little DSL or a custom route an have a look at the methods and path do you have an actue in consecuence with action composition Is a good explanation in a blog post:

the code in scala

```
override def onRouteRequest(req: RequestHeader): Option[Handler] = {
  (req.method, req.path) match {
    case ("GET", "/") => Some(controllers.Application.index)
    case ("POST", "/submit") => Some(controllers.Application.submit)
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

[here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/advanced-routing-in-play-framework.html) is the blog entry.

Comment: I did something like this, but your solution also responds with 405 for paths which do not exist. I.e., if I have only a route `/foo` defined and I call `/bar`, your example will also respond with a 405, but in that case I want the 404.